# Bad UI Design? Having two logos on the top left of the website?

Tags: user-interface, graphical-logo

Well i am currently working on a project doing some UI mockups when certain users wanted to have two logo on the top left ot the website.
One is to indicate what is the website about then another is to indicate that this website is actually belong to this particular sector.

I thought that UI design wise this is very bad because two logos on top left. If users go in initially he won't be able to know which logo means what.

What are your opinions regarding this?

Comment: Is there any chance you can show a mockup, maybe without the exact logos, so we can tell how it looks?  It could be bad or good based on your question but there's no way to know without seeing something.

Comment: I agree, this is completely subjective so there's no hard-and-fast rule to govern this.

Comment: The overriding rule is... Don't Make Me Think... if usability tests show that it is confusing, then it is probably a bad idea to do... so yes, I think there is an objective answer (IE do some usability tests)

Answer (score 4):

It does sound rather confusing, though it may depend on the content of the logos as to whether they are difficult to figure out.

I would recommend getting someone who hasn't used the site to see the mockup and see what they think about it (without guidance)... ie some usability testing.

Check out [Don't Make Me Think by Steve Krug](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321344758)... you will want to do some tests right away after you read that, and he goes into detail about what to do when you get pulled in the wrong direction by people who don't really understand the consequences of the decision.

Answer (score 3):

Surely this is purely subjective and it depends on teh logos and the design of the rest of the site?

I can't think of any examples but I'm sure I've seen multiple logos living quite happilly in one place. That said I'm sure I've seen one logo look completely rubbish...

It depends on your design and the logos.

Answer (score 2):

It can be a problem if both logos have the same level of visual dominance but if you make one look subordinate to the other it should be okay. You can vary them by size, color saturation, and/or relative position (one can be in the corner of the other).

Answer (score 2):

The only place I have seen this is at blues news. 
I don't like it much

http://www.bluesnews.com/

Answer (score 1):

It seems reasonable to me.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to have a meeting with your client and explain to them the potential confusion that some of there customers may have.  Then come up with a solution that you can both agree on.  Something that will suit the flow of the site and still present the information that your client has asked to displayed.

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the logo representing the sector would either be of a subdued nature (muted colors as to not distract from the primary logo), or would be somewhere else on the page (sidebar or footer).

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't seem too bad. Are both the logos the same size?

Suppose a company ABC has a sub-company Alpha. I would think it's perfectly OK to have ABC in the logo (in smaller font, albeit) with Alpha in a more dominant font.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to customize the main logo for the particular sector maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds dependent on the implementation to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need to find some other users, go get drunk